# Incorrect results from a numpy Monte Carlo simulation of investment returns

Tags: python, numpy, simulation, finance, montecarlo

> How much money will you get by investing $10,000 periodically at an average rate of 8% annually for 30 years and using monte carlo simulations?

I am trying to solve a problem like the one described above by using Monte Carlo simulations for the interest rate in python. I came up with the following code and it seems right but it is terribly skewed and I suspect that I did something wrong. Below the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sni(i,n):
    sni = round(((1+i)**n-1)/i,2)
    return sni

df = pd.DataFrame()
investment = 10000
for p in range(1000):
    i = np.random.normal(0.08,0.18)
    lst = []
    for n in range(30):
        final = investment * sni(i,n)
        lst.append(final)
    df[p]=lst
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall the equations out of my sleeve for this, but suspect that you in any case have variation of interest rate over the years, so this exponential stuff wouldn't work.

Then I just did it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab

years = 30
investment = 10000.0

def one_run():
    account = 0
    for n in range(years):
        interest = np.random.normal(0.08, 0.018)
        account = account * (1 + interest) + investment
    return account

df = [one_run() for _ in range(10000)]
    
# ****** everything below here is just plotting

p, b = np.histogram(df,50, density=True)
pylab.plot(b[:-1], p)
pylab.grid()
pylab.xlabel("Return [$]")
pylab.ylabel("Probability density [1/$]")
pylab.show()
```

Also, you varied the interest rate with a scale of 0.18 around 0.08, i.e. quite a lot of times it would be negative. I took the freedom to insert another zero here (to values of 0.08 +- 0.018).